# PHP - Building Select Menu from PHP Array and including non matching database value

Tags: php

I'm generating an HTML Select menu from a PHP array $times which looks like this:

```
Array ( [9:00am] => 9:00am [9:30am] => 9:30am [9:45am] => 9:45am [10:00am] => 10:00am [10:30am] => 10:30am [10:45am] => 10:45am [11:00am] => 11:00am [11:30am] => 11:30am [11:45am] => 11:45am [12:00pm] => 12:00pm [12:30pm] => 12:30pm [12:45pm] => 12:45pm [1:00pm] => 1:00pm [1:30pm] => 1:30pm [1:45pm] => 1:45pm [2:00pm] => 2:00pm [2:30pm] => 2:30pm [2:45pm] => 2:45pm [3:00pm] => 3:00pm [3:30pm] => 3:30pm [3:45pm] => 3:45pm [4:00pm] => 4:00pm [4:30pm] => 4:30pm [4:45pm] => 4:45pm [5:00pm] => 5:00pm [5:30pm] => 5:30pm [5:45pm] => 5:45pm [6:00pm] => 6:00pm [-] => - )
```

I build the select menu as follows, comparing each option to see if it matches the value from the database record so that can be marked as selected:

```
<?php
```

$output = '';

```
foreach($times as $time) {

$time = htmlspecialchars($time);
    if ($time == $record->getField('HotPhotoTime')) {
    $output = "<option value='".$time."' selected='selected' >$time</option>";  
    } else {
    $output = "<option value='".$time."'>$time</option>";  
    }
    echo $output;
```

}
?>

I now need to update this to handle the situation where the value from the database record:

```
$time == $record->getField('HotPhotoTime')
```

is not actually one of the options in the select menu, for example "5:15pm". This currently doesn't show as being selected but any non matching values should be included in the select menu and marked as selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example that fits your needs. Hope this helps.

```
<?php

$times = array(
'01:00' => '01:00',
'02:00' => '02:00',
'03:00' => '03:00',
'04:00' => '04:00',
'05:00' => '05:00',
'06:00' => '06:00',
'07:00' => '07:00',
'08:00' => '08:00',
'09:00' => '09:00'
);

$addThisTime = '04:15';

if(!in_array($addThisTime,$times))
{
    $times[''.$addThisTime.''] = $addThisTime;

    ksort($times);
}



$html = '<select name="yourSelect" id="yourSelectID">';

foreach($times as $v)
{
    $html .= '<option value="'.$v.'" '.(strcmp($v,$addThisTime)==0 ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$v.'</option>';
}

$html .= '</select>';

echo $html;
```